# Why is UIPanGestureRecognizer firing with UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded multiple times?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

What I want to achieve is just to draw a line between the point where the user started the gesture and the point where he ended doing this. I thought that UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded is the state which I need but it is called multiple times. I would be really grateful if anyone could explain me why is this happening and how to catch the last point.

```
- (void)drawingViewDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
CGPoint currentDraggingPosition = [sender locationInView:_drawingView];

if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    _prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
    NSLog(@"---");
}

if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    [self drawLine:_prevDraggingPosition to:currentDraggingPosition];
     NSLog(@"???");
}
_prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
}
```

the log:

> 2016-08-05 17:14:46.086 X[2518:356899] ---
>   2016-08-05 17:14:46.092 X[2518:356899] ???
>   2016-08-05 17:14:46.127 X[2518:356899] ???
>   2016-08-05 17:14:46.153 X[2518:356899] ???
>   2016-08-05 17:14:46.177 X[2518:356899] ???
>   2016-08-05 17:14:46.205 X[2518:356899] ???
>   2016-08-05 17:14:46.226 X[2518:356899] ???
>   2016-08-05 17:14:46.246 X[2518:356899] ???
>   2016-08-05 17:14:46.279 X[2518:356899] ???
>   ...

Comment: what is your log output, that should make it clear if it is firing multiple times. currently it is not certain.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe I'm just using a wrong gesture recognizer

Comment: your code is `sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` it should be `==`

Comment: Oh Thank you)) How did't I notice that)) Add this as an answer so I can vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
    [self drawLine:_prevDraggingPosition to:currentDraggingPosition];
     NSLog(@"???");
}
```

`sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` will evaluate successfully for each type of Gesture state except the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` one.

Change `!=` to `==` and it will work properly.

Comment: np, you are invited to even hang around in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow). Nice place to get help and hang around with other devs